# How to calculate a tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I’m used to the abstract definition of tensor product as an universal solution, but I’m getting trouble in how to calculate one:

Take an example, I think $m\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}/(m)=0$, since $mr\otimes x=r\otimes mx=r\otimes 0=0$, but in Basic algebra written by Jacobson, he says:
$$
m\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}/(m)\cong\mathbb{Z}/(m).
$$

I’m quite confused about this, and the following is another problem:
$$
\mathbb{Z}/(m)\otimes \mathbb{Z}/(n)\cong\mathbb{Z}/(d), \quad d=(m,n)
$$
I can just show that $d \mid m$ and $d \mid n$, but don’t know how to get further

Thanks in advance for anyone’s help!

Comment: Well, $m\Bbb Z\cong\Bbb Z$ as modules / Abelian groups.

Comment: Consider the homomorphism $\mathbb Z\to m\mathbb Z\otimes\mathbb Z/(m)$ defined by $n\mapsto mn\otimes\overline m$. Its kernel is $(m)$, so the isomorphism follows from the 1st isomorphism theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The equation $mr\otimes x=r\otimes mx$ fails (in fact, is non-sense) when $r \notin m\mathbb Z$.
- The map $\mathbb Z/(m) \times \mathbb Z/(n) \to \mathbb Z/(d) \times \mathbb Z/(d)$ given by $$(a+(m),b+(n)) \mapsto (a+(d),b+(d))$$ is a well-defined group homomorphism since $d \mid m$ and $d \mid n$ implies that $(d)$ contains $(m)$ and $(n)$. Then compose with the multiplication map $\mathbb Z/(d) \times \mathbb Z/(d) \to \mathbb Z/(d)$ to obtain a $\mathbb Z$-balanced map $\mathbb Z/(m) \times \mathbb Z/(n) \to \mathbb Z/(d)$. Conclude that the induced group homomophism $\mathbb Z/(m) \otimes \mathbb Z/(n) \to \mathbb Z/(d)$ is an isomorphism considering the order of the groups.